# Kill subprocess in Python in another function?

Tags: python, ubuntu, subprocess, kill

I'm very new in Python. This is my code:

```
def start(self, widget):
    s = subprocess.Popen('myprocess')

def stop(self, widget):
           #what to put here?
```

I'm on Ubuntu. In the first function I start a process, that need the CTRL+C to terminate. Which instructions do I have to put in the stop function to terminate the process?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply solved with a global variable s. So my code become:

```
 s = None

 def start(self, widget):
       global s
       s = subprocess.Popen('myprocess')

 def stop(self, widget):
       s.kill()
```

Comment: better: `def start_process(self, dummy): if self.myprocess: self.stop_process(dummy) \n self.myprocess = Popen('myprocess')` and `def stop_process(self, widget): p, self.myprocess = self.myprocess, None; p.terminate(); widget.after(5000, kill_process, p);`